# VBScript to remove / pinned items to Windows 7 start menu

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, office365, vbscript

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. I'm currently in the process of upgrading about 600 client machines to Office 365 Pro Plus 2016 from 2013. I'm doing this via automation software. That works a charm! What I'm struggling with is removing the current 2013 pinned items and pinning 2016 shortcuts. Asking the users to do this manually isn't an option also, as I have the machines locked down tight, so they're unable to right click on start menu items.
I found the following VBScript on MS forums. I've amended it to what I think 'should' work, however it doesn't. No errors when running the script also.

```
'=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 '           CONSTS
 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT     = &H80000000
 Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER     = &H80000001
 Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE     = &H80000002
 Const HKEY_USERS             = &H80000003
 Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG     = &H80000005

 Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS    = &H17 
 Const CSIDL_PROGRAMS        = &H2 

 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 '          OBJECTS
 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 Set objRegistry            = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
 Set objFSO                = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objApplication        = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
 Set objAllUsersPrograms    = objApplication.NameSpace(CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS)
 Set objUserPrograms        = objApplication.NameSpace(CSIDL_PROGRAMS)

 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 '          VARIABLES
 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 Dim arrSubValues, arrDeleteApps, arrPinApps, strAllUsersProgramsPath

 strAllUsersProgramsPath    = objAllUsersPrograms.Self.Path & "\"
 strUserProgramsPath        = objUserPrograms.Self.Path & "\"
 arrDeleteApps            = Array("displayswitch.lnk", "remote desktop connection.lnk", "sticky notes.lnk", "calculator.lnk", "paint.lnk", "xps viewer.lnk", "windows fax and scan.lnk")

 Call Main

 Sub Main()
     DeleteStartMenuApps HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "", arrDeleteApps

        DoVerb "Unpin from Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Microsoft Office 2013\Word 2013.lnk"
        DoVerb "Unpin from Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Microsoft Office 2013\Excel 2013.lnk"
    DoVerb "Unpin from Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Microsoft Office 2013\PowerPoint 2013.lnk"
        DoVerb "Unpin from Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Microsoft Office 2013\Outlook 2013.lnk"
        DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strUserProgramsPath & "Internet Explorer.lnk"
        DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Programs\Word 2016.lnk"
        DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Programs\Excel 2016.lnk"
    DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk"
        DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Programs\Outlook 2016.lnk"
    DoVerb "Pin to Start Menu", strAllUsersProgramsPath & "Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk"
 End Sub


 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 '     FUNCTIONS AND SUBS
 '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 Function DoVerb(strVerb, strPath)
     On Error Resume Next
         strFolder    = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strPath)
         strFile        = objFSO.GetFileName(strPath)

         Set objFolder        = objApplication.NameSpace(strFolder)
         Set objFolderItem    = objFolder.ParseName(strFile)

         For Each ItemVerb In objFolderItem.Verbs
             If StrComp(Replace(ItemVerb.Name, "&", ""), strVerb, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
                 ItemVerb.DoIt
                 Exit Function
             End If
         Next
     On Error Goto 0
 End Function

 Sub DeleteStartMenuApps(hDefKey, sSubKeyUser, arrDeleteApps)
     If Len(sSubKeyUser) > 0 Then
         sSubKeyName = sSubKeyUser & "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist"
     Else
         sSubKeyName = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist"
     End If    

     objRegistry.EnumKey hDefKey, sSubKeyName, arrSubKeys

     If IsArray(arrSubKeys) Then
         For i = 0 to UBound(arrSubKeys)
             sTempSubKeyName = sSubKeyName & "\" & arrSubKeys(i) & "\Count"
             objRegistry.EnumValues hDefKey, sTempSubKeyName, arrSubValues

             If IsArray(arrSubValues) Then
                 For m = 0 to UBound(arrSubValues)
                     For n = 0 to UBound(arrDeleteApps)
                         If InStr(UCase(RunROT13(arrSubValues(m))), UCase(arrDeleteApps(n))) > 0 Then
                             objRegistry.DeleteValue hDefKey, sTempSubKeyName, arrSubValues(m)
                         End If
                     Next
                 Next
             End If
         Next
     End If
 End Sub


 Function RunROT13(strInput)
     For i = 1 to Len(strInput)
         iChr = Asc(Mid(strInput, i, 1))
         If (iChr >= 65 and iChr <= 77) Or (iChr >= 97 and iChr <= 109) Then 
             strOutput = strOutput & Chr(iChr +13)
         ElseIf (iChr >= 78 and iChr <= 90) Or (iChr >= 110 and iChr <= 122) Then 
             strOutput = strOutput & Chr(iChr -13) 
         Else
             strOutput = strOutput & Chr(iChr)
         End If
     Next

     RunROT13 = strOutput
 End Function

 Function IsProgramInstalled(objRegistry, strProgramDisplayName)
     intRegistryHive    = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     strRegistryKey    = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

     objRegistry.EnumKey intRegistryHive, strRegistryKey, arrSubkeys

     IsProgramInstalled = FALSE

     For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
         strDisplayName = ReadRegistryValue(objRegistry, "STRING", intRegistryHive, strRegistryKey & "\" & strSubkey, "DisplayName")

         If UCase(strDisplayName) = UCase(strProgramDisplayName) Then
             IsProgramInstalled = TRUE
             Exit For
         End If
     Next
 End Function

 Function ReadRegistryValue(objRegistry, strType, intRegistryHive, strSubKeyName, sValueName)
     Select Case UCase(strType)
         Case "DWORD"
             objRegistry.GetDWORDValue intRegistryHive, strSubKeyName, sValueName, strValue
         Case "EXPANDEDSTRING"
             objRegistry.GetExpandedStringValue intRegistryHive, strSubKeyName, sValueName, strValue
         Case "MULTISTRING"
             objRegistry.GetMultiStringValue intRegistryHive, strSubKeyName, sValueName, strValue
         Case "STRING"
             objRegistry.GetStringValue intRegistryHive, strSubKeyName, sValueName, strValue
     End Select

     ReadRegistryValue = strValue
 End Function
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> No errors when running the script also.

You need to remove this one and NEVER use it again:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

> Without an On Error statement, any run-time error that occurs is
>   fatal: an error message is displayed, and execution stops.

Comment: Right, OK. Removed that. It now errors complaining about line 57 char 10 which is...  

Set objFolderItem    = objFolder.ParseName(strFile)

Error - Object required 'objFolder

Comment: Then the object can't be created at  Set objFolder        = objApplication.NameSpace(strFolder). You need to debug, take a look at my article in codeproject: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/864659/How-to-Debug-Visual-Basic-Script-with-Visual-Studi

Comment: Ah right, I see. Hmm, OK. Well I'm not coder so I'd be wasting my time trying to debug. I've worked around it anyway using group policy to push the required shortcuts to the local machines, then a mix of batch files and registry edits to remove old items and pin the new shortcuts that are pushed. That works.

Thanks for you help anyway.